# How to open the keyboard automatically on UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface, uitextfield, builder

I have a very simple table and when tocuh a cell it opens a new view with one UITextfield. All I want is that the keyboard will automatically opens, without the user have to touch the UITextfield.

Its all done in Interface Builder, so I am not sure how I do this. I guess I need to set the focus at some point ?

Thanks

Answer (score 139, accepted):

To cause the keyboard to show up immediately you'll need to set the text field as the first responder using the following line:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

You may want to place this in the `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: I recommend -viewDidAppear:, since this generates animations. Generating animations in -viewWillAppear can lead to graphic artifacts, since you're not on the screen yet. Since you almost certainly want it every time you come on screen, -viewDidLoad is likely redundant (it happens every time the view is loaded from disk, which is somewhat unpredictable, so isn't a good place for visual effects).

Comment: Do you need to import the ```UITextViewDelegate``` delegate when doing this and then connect it to the delegate in IB?

Comment: for swift 3 :
`override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }`

Answer (score 13):

Swift 3 & 4:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: And to avoid weird side effects, call also `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer adding the first responder on the main thread -

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

This will come in handy when the view controller view is added as a subview.

Comment: I'm pretty sure DispatchQueue.main.async is unnecessary since viewDidAppear is run on the main thread anyways

Comment: true but in many other cases, you have to remrember to do that!